# Относительный путь к другой странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Встретился с такой проблемой - не могу верно указать путь до второй страницы,самый простой шаг(выйти из той папки, где лежит основная страница - выполнен), а дальше ступор. Если быть конкретнее - есть две папки, в каждой лежит файл(меняется только номер страницы). И из первой страницы нужно обратиться ко второй.[image: Папки, в которых лежат страницы]

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> -->
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick = "window.location = 'Test2/../Test_Site2.html';"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если первая страница находится в `Test1`, тогда относительный адрес должен быть `'../Test2/Test_Site2.html'`.